# Is there any message lost when using replication as HA policy

Tags: activemq-classic, jboss-amq

I am using jboss amq7.1/apache amq, When using replication as the HA policy for my cluster, it is documented that all data synchronization is done over the network, All persistent data received by the master broker is synchronized to the slave when the master drops from the network. A slave broker first needs to synchronize all existing data from the master broker before becoming capable of replacing it.

Per my understanding, if master broker is crashed instead of shutdown by administrator, no persistent data can be synced, therefore messages persisted in journal of master will be lost if the disk used by journal is broken, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is not correct.

All persistent data received by the master broker is replicated to the slave when the master broker receives it *so that* when the master broker drops from the network (e.g. due to a crash) the slave can replace the master.

Replicating the data from the master to the slave *when* the master drops from the network would completely defeat the purpose of high availability.

Comment: hi Justin, many thanks. But it's not my suggestion to replicate data when the master drops, it's documented on the official url: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_amq/7.1/html/using_amq_broker/high_availability#replication  you can check 21.1. Journal Replication and High Availability， key word: "All persistent data received by the master broker is synchronized to the slave when the master drops from the network. A slave broker first needs to synchronize all existing data from the master broker before becoming capable of replacing it." .

Comment: And this is the reason I asked for clarification.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of the source of this idea.  For future reference, such relevant links would be useful in the original question rather than a subsequent comment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if HA is configured as Master/Slave, whether network or journal replicated, the receipt of a message to the broker is FIRST replicated and ONLY if successful, it will be confirmed as received to the client.